# Error: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined Graphql

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

estoy implementando subscripciones en graphql, estoy utilizando [type-graphql](https://typegraphql.com/) para los resolvers, la aplicacion funciona bien, cuando creo una publicacion, antes de responder al usuario creo un `pulisher` para activar la subscripcion, pero cuando la recibo en el cliente me aparece el siguiente error

```
Error: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined
at new ApolloError (index.ts:49)
at QueryManager.ts:708
at Object.next (Observable.js:322)
at notifySubscription (Observable.js:135)
at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:235)
at iteration.ts:13
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at iterateObserversSafely (iteration.ts:13)
at Object.next (Concast.ts:171)
at Object.handler (client.ts:218)
at SubscriptionClient.processReceivedData (client.ts:651)
at WebSocket.client.onmessage (client.ts:593)
```

este error me aparece por consola, este es el metodo con el que actualizo mi hook que contiene las publicaciones

```
const { loading: loadingSubPub, error: errorSubPub, data: dataSubPub } = useSubscription(get_subscription_publications);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(errorSubPub) // es el error que aparece en consola
    if (dataSubPub) {
      const { publications } = dataSubPub;
      return setPublicaciones((prev) => {
        return [...prev, publications];
      });
    }
  }, [dataSubPub, errorSubPub]);
```

de esta manera guardo la publicacion del usuario y llamo a `publisher`:

```
@Authorized()
@Mutation((returns) => PublicationResponse)
  async post(
    @Arg("data") data: IPublicacionInput,
    @Ctx() { Models, user }: any,
    @PubSub("PUBLICACIONES") publish: any
  ) {
    try {
      const usr: any = await Models.Usuarios.findById(user._id)
      const publicacion = new Models.Publicaciones(data)
      publicacion.usuario = usr._id
      usr?.publicaciones.addToSet(publicacion._id)
      await usr.save()
      const new_publicacion = await publicacion.save()
      const np = await Models.Publicaciones.findById(new_publicacion._id).populate("usuario")
      publish(np)
      return {success: true, message: "Publicacion creada con exito"}
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return {error: true, message: "Intentalo mas tarde." };
    }
  }
```

y de esta menera manejo la subscripcion

```
@Subscription((returns) => IPublicacion,{topics: "PUBLICACIONES"})
async publications(
    @Root() publicacion: IPublicacion,
  ) {
    return publicacion
  }
```

sencillo, pero no me devuelve la nueva publicación, me sorprende por que estaba funcionando bien, me llama mucho la atención el `Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined` por que no estoy utilizando plugins.

si necesitan mas info, con gusto lo agregare.

voy agregar mi configuraciones de apollo:

1. servidor

---

```
async function main() {
  //CONFIG
  config();
  const app = express();
  const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 4000;
  const serverHTTP = createServer(app);

  //SERVER APOLLO
  const serverApollo = new ApolloServer({
    subscriptions: {
      path: "/subscriptions",
      onConnect: async (connectionParams: any) => {
        console.log("nuevo usuario conectado")
        const { authToken }: any = connectionParams;
        if (authToken) {
          const payload: any = decode(authToken);
          const user = await Models.Usuarios.findById(payload._id)
          return { Models, user };
        }
      },
    },
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [
        AuthenticationResolver,
        UserResolver,
        PublicationResolver,
        //SUBCRIPTIONS
        PublicationSubscriptionResolver,
      ],
      authChecker: ({ context }) => {
        if (!context.user) return false;
        return true;
      },
      authMode: "null",
    }),
    context: async ({ req, res, connection }) => {
      if (connection) return connection.context;
      const token: any = req.headers.authorization;
      if (!token) return { req, res, Models };
      if (token) {
        const payload: any = decode(token);
        const user = await Models.Usuarios.findById(payload._id)
        return { req, res, Models, user };
      }
    }
  });

  serverApollo.applyMiddleware({ app });
  serverApollo.installSubscriptionHandlers(serverHTTP)

  serverHTTP.listen(PORT, async () => {
    console.log(`Server http://localhost:${PORT}${serverApollo.graphqlPath}`);
    console.log(`Subscriptions ws://localhost:${PORT}${serverApollo.subscriptionsPath}`);
  });
}

main();
```

2. Este es el cliente

---

```
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
uri: "ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions",
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: localStorage.getItem("access_token")
    }
  }
});

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? token : "",
    }
  }
});

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink),
);

const Client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas Apollo:

> Error: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined at new ApolloError
> (index.ts:49)

Me parece que es un problema similar a este :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727449/graphql-cannot-read-property-query-of-undefined

en el cual no se pueden leer propiedades:

> No debe utilizar middleware de `express-graphql` y `apollo-server` en su
> aplicación express. Debido a que `postgraphile-apollo-server` funciona
> explícitamente con ApolloServer, elimine `express-graphql` por completo.
> Es probable que tener ambos middleware cause problemas inesperados, ya
> que escuchan en las mismas rutas.
>
> Apollo ha abandonado GraphQL a favor de GraphQL Playground. **Si desea
> utilizar GraphiQL con Apollo, puede utilizar un paquete como
> [**express-graphiql-middleware**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphiql-middleware)**.

Comment: estoy utilizando `apollo-server-express`, sera este el problema ? debo utilizar solo `apollo-server` para crear el servior de apollo ?

Comment: no estoy utilizando middlewares, solamente utilizo `apollo-server-express` para inciar el servidor de apollo